# Problem with auto generated Register number

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating registration number by using following code, but the issue is that when more than one browser open forms . for example two operator when open form at same time in their computers, then same code loaded on both forms, which create issues, (remember i cannot make it unique ID or primary key becuase in my situation duplicate code can be entered as per situation, but it should not be open in two forms at the same time. Can any one suggest me solution for that

```
<?php 
$CI = "L5"; //Example only
$CIcnt = strlen($CI);
$offset = $CIcnt + 6;

// Get the current month and year as two-digit strings 
$month = date("m"); // e.g. 09 
$year = date("y"); // e.g. 23  

// Get the last bill number from the database 
$query = "SELECT patientno FROM iap2 ORDER BY patientno DESC"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
// Use mysqli_fetch_assoc() to get an associative array of the fetched row 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
// Use $row[‘patientno’] to get the last bill number 
$lastid = $row['patientno'];     

// Check if the last bill number is empty or has a different month or year
if(empty($lastid) || (substr($lastid, $CIcnt + 1, 2) != $month) || (substr($lastid, $CIcnt + 3, 2) != $year)) { 
    // Start a new sequence with 0001 
    $number = "$CI-$month$year-0001"; 
} else { 
    // Increment the last four digits by one 
    $idd = substr($lastid, $offset); // e.g. 0001 
    echo $idd;
    $id = str_pad($idd + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); // e.g. 0002 
    $number = "$CI-$month$year-$id"; 
} 
echo $number; 
?>
```

Comment: Duplicate code can be entered? Well how about you use table locking so it can't?

Comment: Why not just use an autoincrement field to generate the ID? It's just an identifier, so it doesn't need a fancy format. Being unique should be perfectly sufficient for it to do its job. Trying to ascribe additional meaning to IDs by complicating their contents is a common design mistake.

Comment: ^ this too , but there could be situations where the data is the same but it creates 2 unique keys, so it gets in there twice, such as bob.smith for id 1 and bob.smith for id2 as well.

Comment: @easleyfixed that would be true if two computer users are working on entering the same piece of data. Hopefully that doesn't happen, and if it does it's at least partly an organisation issue rather than a technology one. But yes it could be mitigated by setting "unique" constraints on relevant (combinations of) fields in the table, if it makes logical sense to do so. That's a slightly different issue though than having 2 identical IDs generated for different records, which I think is the OP's concern here.

Comment: @ADyson sir actually the format have some meaning, first 2 alphabet displaying company name, next 4 showing yea rand month and last four showing auto generated number

Comment: `actually the format have some meaning`...which is exactly what I've warned you against doing, if you read my comment fully! An ID emphatically should **not** have **any** other meaning than "this (random) number uniquely represents record X". If you need to store other information about the record, store it in other fields, separately. Such information as company name etc. is not relevant or needed, just for an ID.

Comment: Basically this question is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) because there is absolutely no need for any of this code to exist at all. Use a mysql auto-increment field, and simplify your life!

Comment: @ADyson, if i keep it separately then how id will reverse when month will change, in my case after every month, id need to be start from 1 again

Comment: No you don't need that. What possible reason could there be for doing that?

Comment: @ADyson i think i should try trigger at back end

Comment: Note: If you want to display records which contain this kind of sequentially generated number, for someone else's benefit, you can absolutely still do that. But you should generate the number separately - either at the time you create the output, or as a separate thing in your code, maybe after the record is created. But _don't_ try to use it to uniquely identify the record, and _don't_ generate it _before_ the record is created - because you're create exactly the race condition you're suffering from now.

Comment: `i think i should try trigger`...no, no, no and no again. And that won't necessarily prevent duplicates anyway. Read my lips: the entire idea you have got here is completely wrong-headed. Auto-increment fields exist for very good reasons - to prevent the situation you have found yourself in. Just use it, and stop trying to find workarounds to a problem which has already been solved many years ago. As I said above, if you need to generate some sequence number for a display, do that separately, not as the ID when creating the record.

Comment: @ADyson actually its hospital app, where more then 10000 patient visit every month, therefore to remember there registration number, i want to reverse last four digit when month change

Comment: They don't need to remember their registration number, you can give it to them, they can write it down or store it in their phone, or whatever. Do you try to memorise everybody's phone number, and all your usernames and IDs for all the apps you use??

Comment: Quite frankly, if you are trying implement a "hospital app" with such minimal knowledge of systems design and concurrency etc that you would even attempt this idea, I am a bit worried about the security of the data, the reliability of the app, the compliance with regulatory and legal requirements, and ultimately the safety and the patients. Hopefully this is just a learning project for a student course?? If not, it's time to hire some experts.

Comment: @ADyson sir then suggest me how i can make number, I can use three fields in mysql table and later concatenate it with auto incremented IDs

Comment: @ADyson yes its learning project, I am University student,

Comment: Yes that sounds like a sensible approach. As long as the auto-incremented field is part of it, there should be no danger of duplicates

Comment: @ADyson Yes that sounds like a sensible approach , but is there anyway by which I can revser last four digit just digit in concatinate field

Comment: You could maybe use SQL to generate a sequence number grouped by month and year, after the record is inserted.

Comment: @ADyson ok thanks i am going to use it